# nunit keeps running after response.redirect with end response

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I'm writing some unit tests in C# against my WebFormsMVP code.  Within my code I have some items where if a certain condition is met - I call

```
Response.Redirect("urlToGoTo", true);
```

But it seems that all code AFTER the redirect still executes.  Is this a bug in nunit?  Or is there something I can do besides writing code like:

```
if(somethingTrue){
    Response.Redirect("toUrl", true);
    return;
}

var keepGoing = someMoreProcesses();
Response.Redirect("toSomeOtherUrl", true);
```

**--Begin Edit--**

In the following code - if I have a test that checks that Response.Redirect was called once - it will show it was called multiple times even though the **Response** should have ended after the first **Redirect**

```
if(somethingTrue){
    //This should end the response!
    Response.Redirect("toUrl", true); 
}
//but this still runs in the unit test
var keepGoing = someMoreProcesses();
Response.Redirect("toSomeOtherUrl", true);
```

**--End Edit--**

I should also state that I am setting up a moq'd http context like:

```
 HttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
 Request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
 Response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
 Session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();

 HttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(Request.Object);
 HttpContext.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(Response.Object);
 HttpContext.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(Session.Object);
```

Is there something I can setup on the moq Response?

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can avoid you accessing Response.Redirect during the Unit Testing. One way to tackle this is to create a wrapper class around the Response.Redirect("toUrl", true); and now a. You can make sure stub out the method in your Unit Test. b You can verify if the Response.Redirect called.

```
public interface IHttpContextWrapper
{
    void Reditect(strinh url)
}
```

You implementation

```
 public class HttpContextWrapper :IHttpContextWrapper
 {
     publlic void Reditect(string url)
     {
            Response.Redirect(url, true);       
     }
 }
```

IN you Sut (system under test), inject this class as dependency and call the Redirect

In your Unit Test you can stub/mock the HttpContextWrapper.Redirect method.

**UPDATE:**

One of the questions "Is this a bug in nunit?"
No, pretty sure this is related the test execution context. You running on a test execution context -stubbed HttpContext and stubbed Response object. These won't work as usual and this might be causing the execution to continue even after the Response.Redirect.

There has been an approach taken to eliminate this problem and I came across with the below blog post. It seems that if you can configure your stubbed Response object to throw an exception during the Redirect, and it will break the execution so you can Verify against. Please see more info below.

http://joelabrahamsson.com/performing-and-testing-redirects-with-aspnet-web-forms-mvp/

Comment: Thanks Rag - but I think my unit tests would still run the other code.  I've modified my question a bit to hopefully be more clear

Comment: @ajwaka - I have updated answer with addition detail. Hope that help you to find a solution.